# How can I use CCClippingNode to trim the top and bottom from a CCTableView?

Tags: ios, cocos2d, viewport, clipping

I'm fairly new to Cocos2d and struggling with sizing a `CCTableView`. How can its height be controlled so that I have space at the top and the bottom?

I'm trying to visually wrap the top and bottom of my table view with a sprite, to provide the look and feel of a frame. But when I touch the table view, to scroll it up or down, it occupies most of the screen vertically. I thought the `contentSize` would alter where each cell appears and disappears from the top and bottom, but changing it had no effect.

Having had a Google about, I'm reading that I have to use a Clipping Node with a Stencil? Coming from UIkit, this seems like a bit of a faff. Would anyone like to hazard at a tutorial, bit of code with a simple `CCTableView` representation, sat in the middle of the scene where each cell appears and disappears under a content frame?

Comment: I started a thread on Stackoverflow, too. See link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26560732/how-can-i-use-ccclippingnode-to-cut-the-top-and-bottom-of-a-cctableview

Answer (score 1):

I ended up altering the contentSize of the CCTableView.

So,

```
someTableView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(200, 300);
```

...and then I placed a CCSprite over it with a hole in the middle that had transparency. This way, the table view was clipped how I wanted it clipped. I added the tableView to my scene with a lower z-order than that of the sprite. Did not need the complexity of what I was describing above.